# Incorrect Position on <div> Element

Tags: css, html, alignment

I'm trying to make a simple yet interactive webpage for my school. Our current homepage we use for links is plain and boring.

I've created this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zulfe/mKYaL/18/)

But when I open the 'Student Links', the 'PHHS Website' button seems to automatically position itself ~50 pixels up. 
Code because I have to:

```
<a class="itemLink" href="http://hcps.us/phhs/">
     <div class="itemStudentsLink" id="PHHSWebsite">
           <p class="itemText">PHHS Website</p>
     </div>
</a>
```

If anyone knows why it's acting like this, please tell me. I'm not sure why this problem occurs.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: I dont see why would  someone downvote this Question? Pretty Legit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with the vertical alignment of the blocks and the fact that one of the block's text goes onto two lines.  Add

```
.itemStudentsLink {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/mKYaL/19/